# Issues deploying a Java application to Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, deployment, javadb

I built a simple Java web application. It provides a series of RESTful APIs for the user to carry out certain operations on a Java DB through a web interface. I used NetBeans environment during the development, and Glassfish for testing.

Now that I finished it, I would like to be able to deploy it on another machine using binaries (although as for now I use the same machine until I learn how to do it).

I installed Tomcat 7, and moved the .war file into Tomcat's webapp folder. The application deploys. Thereafter I try to read some data from the databse using a button I created just for this, but get the following error

[image]

I am not sure what went wrong, but I have two theories.

1) The web application cannot connect to the database. Yet when I attempted to run the application again, after starting JavaDB from NetBeans, there was no difference.

2) Somehow, the application cannot reach the Node service. I assumed that there will be no need to change the API links while moving the app, but perhaps I was wrong.

Or maybe there is some other issue I did not consider? I will be grateful for any advice about how to properly deploy such an application.

EDIT: The issue was solved by using TomEE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is come from your application server of choice.
TomCat is only a servlet container (means it only support Servlet/JSP).
Any other feature (JAX-RS, CDI etc) require a Java EE certified server e.g. GlassFish, WildFly,Payara, WebLogic, OpenLiberty or TomEE.

[TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/) could be your best bet if you want to use TomCat in your production or test environment, it is basically TomCat + Java EE other feature.

EDIT:
TomEE don't have a GUI for JNDI datasource configuration like GlassFish, you need to edit conf/tomee.xml

```
<Resource id="myDataSource" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    jdbcDriver = org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
    jdbcUrl = jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/dbname
    userName = app
    password = app
</Resource>
```

And in your java code:

```
@Path("resources")
@Stateless
public class MyResources{
    @Resource(name="myDataSource")
    DataSource dataSource;

    @GET
    public Response SomeMethod(){
         //Do stuff here
    }
}
```

You can check [here](http://tomee.apache.org/datasource-config.html) for more detail configuration on data source.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've installed TomEE, and put the .war file there. The app runs properly, but when I try to grab data from the database, I receive a series of Java Persistence errors, "user lacks privilege or object not found" regarding the single table used by the application, even though I have started the database from Netbeans. Do I have to run a JavaDB on the TomEE as well?

Comment: You need to start the javadb in standalone mode. %JAVADB_HOME%/bin/startNetworkServer.bat 
Setting up the data source is straight forward. You need to add a resource entry to tomee.xml in TomEE/conf directory