# REST Application deployment issues on Tomcat 8.5.33

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, glassfish-4.1, apache-tomee

I had developed a REST based web application in **Netbeans-8.2** using **Glassfish-4.1.1**.
Now development is finished and I want to deploy it on a server for testing purpose. I am using **Tomcat-8.5.33** for deployment using **WAR** file.
After I move **WAR** file to **webapps** folder, when i try to access the application everything works fine except for the web services which provides data to the application. **JSP** is displaying perfectly, issue is with the resources which provides data. When i try to access the web service it shows error.
[Error when try to access REST service.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDxNM.png)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609468/issues-deploying-a-java-application-to-tomcat.

Answer of this question says that **TomEE** is required and not Tomcat, but if my memory works correct **Netbeans** have both **Tomcat** and **TomEE** in a single bundle. Isn't it?

I dont know what configuration needed to be changed when migrating an application from **Glassfish-4.1.1** to **Tomcat-8.5.33**. Everything works perfectly fine when running on Glassfish, but no luck on Tomcat.

I want a detailed explanation of this issue and how to solve it.

Tomcat stacktrace:

```
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.274 INFO [http-nio-8082-exec-36] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=LocationFacadeREST, ejb-name=LocationFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:816)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatJndiBuilder.mergeJava(TomcatJndiBuilder.java:262)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatJavaJndiBinder.lifecycleEvent(TomcatJavaJndiBinder.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:629)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1650)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.274 INFO [http-nio-8082-exec-36] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=MFcltydeptFacadeREST, ejb-name=MFcltydeptFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.275 INFO [http-nio-8082-exec-36] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=AuthoritytagFacadeREST, ejb-name=AuthoritytagFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:946)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.276 INFO [http-nio-8082-exec-36] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=MTypeFacadeREST, ejb-name=MTypeFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.277 INFO [http-nio-8082-exec-36] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=TMemfineFacadeREST, ejb-name=TMemfineFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.277 INFO [http-nio-8082-exec-36] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=TOtherissueFacadeREST, ejb-name=TOtherissueFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.278 INFO [http-nio-8082-exec-36] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=TDamageFacadeREST, ejb-name=TDamageFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.279 INFO [http-nio-8082-exec-36] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=UserdetailFacadeREST, ejb-name=UserdetailFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.280 INFO [http-nio-8082-exec-36] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=TMemdueFacadeREST, ejb-name=TMemdueFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.281 INFO [http-nio-8082-exec-36] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=MBkstatusFacadeREST, ejb-name=MBkstatusFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.282 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=SBindingSetFacadeREST, ejb-name=SBindingSetFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.283 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=SSubdetailFacadeREST, ejb-name=SSubdetailFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.284 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=MMemberFacadeREST, ejb-name=MMemberFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.284 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=ReporttemplatemainFacadeREST, ejb-name=ReporttemplatemainFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.285 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=BiblifilesFacadeREST, ejb-name=BiblifilesFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.286 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=LanguagemasterFacadeREST, ejb-name=LanguagemasterFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.287 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=SLooseissuemappingFacadeREST, ejb-name=SLooseissuemappingFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.288 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=IllExtissueBiblocationFacadeREST, ejb-name=IllExtissueBiblocationFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.289 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=IllLibrestrictFacadeREST, ejb-name=IllLibrestrictFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.290 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=ABudgetTransactionFacadeREST, ejb-name=ABudgetTransactionFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.291 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=MemcardtemplatemainFacadeREST, ejb-name=MemcardtemplatemainFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.292 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=AAmtReceiveFacadeREST, ejb-name=AAmtReceiveFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.293 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=BiblidetailsLocationFacadeREST, ejb-name=BiblidetailsLocationFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.294 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=MemcardtemplatesubFacadeREST, ejb-name=MemcardtemplatesubFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.295 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=IllReqprocdmpFacadeREST, ejb-name=IllReqprocdmpFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.296 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=Tplfxfld008FacadeREST, ejb-name=Tplfxfld008FacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.296 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=TGroupIssueFacadeREST, ejb-name=TGroupIssueFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.297 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=TBookbankissuereturnFacadeREST, ejb-name=TBookbankissuereturnFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.298 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=BiblocationIssueReserveFacadeREST, ejb-name=BiblocationIssueReserveFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.299 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=BiblidetailsFacadeREST, ejb-name=BiblidetailsFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.299 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=TLostFacadeREST, ejb-name=TLostFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.300 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=TBInvoiceFacadeREST, ejb-name=TBInvoiceFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.301 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=SSupplierDetailFacadeREST, ejb-name=SSupplierDetailFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.302 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=MCtgryColllectionFacadeREST, ejb-name=MCtgryColllectionFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.302 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=SParallelFacadeREST, ejb-name=SParallelFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.303 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=MWeekoffdayFacadeREST, ejb-name=MWeekoffdayFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.303 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=TReplaceFacadeREST, ejb-name=TReplaceFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.303 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=SSupplierFacadeREST, ejb-name=SSupplierFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.303 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=ReserveBiblocationFacadeREST, ejb-name=ReserveBiblocationFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.303 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=MBranchmasterFacadeREST, ejb-name=MBranchmasterFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.303 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=BookTransferBiblocationFacadeREST, ejb-name=BookTransferBiblocationFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.303 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=TBindingFacadeREST, ejb-name=TBindingFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.303 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=AInvoiceFacadeREST, ejb-name=AInvoiceFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.303 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=IssuedInformationFacadeREST, ejb-name=IssuedInformationFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.303 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=SSubInvdetailFacadeREST, ejb-name=SSubInvdetailFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.303 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=BiblitemplatemainFacadeREST, ejb-name=BiblitemplatemainFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.303 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=BHeadsFacadeREST, ejb-name=BHeadsFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.303 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=CtgryMediaIssueReserveFacadeREST, ejb-name=CtgryMediaIssueReserveFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.303 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=SEditionFacadeREST, ejb-name=SEditionFacadeREST, container=Default Stateless Container)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.303 INFO [272] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps using context file F:\SRA29012018\SoulRestApp\build\web\META-INF\context.xml
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.318 INFO [272] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Deployed Application(path=F:\SRA29012018\SoulRestApp\build\web)
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.318 SEVERE [272] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal Error merging Java EE JNDI entries in to war /SoulRestApp: Exception: null
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createSubcontexts(NamingContextListener.java:1253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addEnvironment(NamingContextListener.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.processGlobalResourcesChange(NamingContextListener.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.propertyChange(NamingContextListener.java:382)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.addEnvironment(NamingResourcesImpl.java:302)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBNamingResource.addEnvironment(OpenEJBNamingResource.java:78)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatJndiBuilder.mergeRef(TomcatJndiBuilder.java:403)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatJndiBuilder.mergeJndi(TomcatJndiBuilder.java:125)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1389)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:629)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1650)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:946)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.848 INFO [272] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.864 INFO [272] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deployment of configuration descriptor [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\TomEE\conf\Catalina\localhost\SoulRestApp.xml] has finished in [8,656] ms
28-Aug-2018 12:53:47.864 INFO [http-nio-8082-exec-35] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SoulRestApp]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
```

I had changed the server from Tomcat-8.5.33 to TomEE-plus-7.0.5.
Project runs perfectly but unable to access services.

Comment: Are you using jersey?

Comment: Could you please post error stacktrace from Tomcat logs?

Comment: Stacktrace of tomcat long is too long to post, but here is some part of it. @Ivan                                                                                                         **28-Aug-2018 11:56:38.256 FINE [http-nio-8081-exec-51] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/F:/SRA29012018/SoulRestApp/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.8.1.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.**

Comment: This is not an error as it was printed with `[FINE]` label. Please add whole exception stacktrace to the question. It is impossible to understand the issue without it

Comment: Issue solved. The issue was TomEE instance didn't had any datasource to connect. What i tried is setup a **TomEE-7.0.5** instance and then configured the database reference in TomEE configuration files, and also added the same reference in **web.xml** of project. And it works perfectly after that. Now my application is perfectly working in both TomEE and Glassfish. Thanks @Ivan

Answer (score 0):

Look at the first line of the exception it says clearly you are using @stateless ejb annotation in your resource class Facade . Ejb will work only 
In application server glassfish , Tomee . To fix your problem remove all @stateless & @ejb annotation from your code then run in Tomcat. It will work good. Good luck